# port forwarding service -> container

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm

I have one service which contains one container.

in container there is django server with port 8000 open.

And my service and container environment is here below

`docker container ls`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                   NAMES
500e9b49dd35        registry:5000/myapp/djangosrc:latest   "python manage.py ru…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes             80/tcp, 8000-8001/tcp   django_python.ti4iq9vbe6b6tskrnfni1r194.prc5s92pxrrfeerjj0oqnjykl
```

`docker service ls`

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                    PORTS
l1z94x8t69li        django_python       global              1/1                 registry:5000/myapp/djangosrc:latest   *:8001->8001/tcp, *:8082->8000/tcp
```

So when I wget inside the container,it works well.

```
/ #docker container exec -it 500e9b49dd35 wget localhost:8000

index.html        100%[===================>]  77.36K  --.-KB/s    in 0s
```

However I can't connect with `wget localhost:8082`

```
Connecting to localhost:8082 (127.0.0.1:8082)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

Is there something I misunderstood???

Please help me. I really welcome any help or hint.

---

These are test suggested by @BMitch (thank you !!)

```
docker run --rm --net container:500e9b49dd35 nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt

Status: Downloaded newer image for nicolaka/netshoot:latest
State   Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port  Process  
LISTEN  0        128           127.0.0.11:40105          0.0.0.0:*              
LISTEN  0        10             127.0.0.1:8000           0.0.0.0:*
```

---

I solved the problem.

This is because of server, not port forwarding.

my server is

`python manage.py runserver`

it binds `127.0.0.1`

so I changed to

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

I can access from outside.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show the output of `docker run --rm --net container:500e9b49dd35 nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt`

Comment: Thank you again!. I pasted the log in the article.

Comment: I solved the problem is quite bad mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this output, you can see that your application inside the container is listening on 127.0.0.1, or loopback:

```
docker run --rm --net container:500e9b49dd35 nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt

Status: Downloaded newer image for nicolaka/netshoot:latest
State   Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port  Process  
LISTEN  0        128           127.0.0.11:40105          0.0.0.0:*              
LISTEN  0        10             127.0.0.1:8000           0.0.0.0:*
```

Networking in namespaced in docker, including the loopback interface. So each container has its own loopback interface, separate from the host and other containers by default. You need to configure the application to listen on all interfaces in order for the application to be reachable from outside of the container, including for published ports to work. In IPv4, that means listening on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. This needs to be configured in your application itself, docker doesn't control the ports used by the application, it only forwards to those ports.

Comment: I see. I noticed that when reading about runserver of python django ,but your explanation is great help for me.